# Hide items with same column value in a view

Tags: list, list-view, view

I have the following list list view where the second column is **text type**. How do I show only one record for each of the values? Basically I do not want to show more than one record where the second column has the same value.

thanks!

[image]

Comment: You could use group by on the second column, other then that you would have to use code.

Comment: Even though this does the trick for a list view, forgot to mention this is meant to be shown in a calendar view.